# AngularJS - Delete an item with dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my AngularJS web application, I have a list of objects connected to Mongo DB. I would like to give the possibility to the user to delete it by proving a trash icon.
No problem until here: when the trash icon is clicked, the project disappears. My next step is to add a dialog that asks to confirm that the user would really like to delete it. Here is my problem.

When I click on the trash, it appears the dialog asking the confirmation. When "Delete" is clicked the object do not delete, only if you click on it another time, it deletes.

Here the html:

```
<div ng-model="projects" ng-repeat='project in projects'>
    <div class="list_projects"> 
       <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-2x"></i>  {{project.project_name}} 
    </div>

    <a ng-click="deleteDialog(project)">  
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
    </a>

    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete project" style="display: none;">
      <div>
         Are you sure to delete "{{project.project_name}}" project?
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the controller:

```
 // delete a project
 $scope.deleteProject = function() {

    var delThis = $http.delete('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/timeman/collections/Projects/' +
                  $scope.proj._id.$oid,
                  {
                       params : { apiKey : apiKeyString }
                   });

    delThis.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.getProjects();
    });

    delThis.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
         throw new Error("Something got wrong with delete");
    });
 };

    $scope.deleteDialog = function(proj) {
        $scope.proj = proj;
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 160,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Delete: function() {
                    $scope.deleteProject();
                    $scope.proj = null;
                    $scope.projpos = -1;
                    $scope.projForm.$setPristine();
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }
        }
    });
  };
```

I hope I was clear and gave enough information to undestand my problem. If it is not the case, I will be please to provide more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap `Delete: function()` with `$apply()` to invoke digest cycle . Something like:

```
 Delete: function() {
                 $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.deleteProject();
                    $scope.proj = null;
                    $scope.projpos = -1;
                    $scope.projForm.$setPristine();
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 });                    
            },
```

or call after row `$( this ).dialog( "close" );`: `$scope.$apply()`.

But I prefer to use 1st option

*As a side note*

Try to put all DOM manipulations/update (`$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog`) into directive but not in controller( for better design).

Comment: great! it works! thank you! also for your last advice!

Comment: Just another little issue: when I press delete it deletes (yuhuu!) but the dialog do not close...

Comment: im not familiar with `$( this ).dialog( "close" );` . can't help here

Comment: I found a solution from here:http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-model-dialog-close.

Comment: Mainly instead of  $( this ).dialog( "close" ); I put $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close"); Thank you for the rest!